Scalatest 3.0.8 PrivateMethodTester can't find private method named X
I have a base class that has a protected method called "validateOptPwd". This gets inherited in a test and then called via PrivateMethodTester.
val validateOptPwdMethod: PrivateMethod[Future[xException]] =
    PrivateMethod[Future[xException]](Symbol("validateOptPwd"))

The error I get is:
Can't find a private method named: ymbol(validateOptPwd)

The fact that it complains about "ymbol" and misses the letter "S" suggest to me that maybe some other framework I use, breaks stuff. Some json perhaps (?).
I am also upgrading our project from scala 2.11 to 2.13 which demands other frameworks to be upgraded.
I was wondering. Do you guys know if there is a framework on which scalatest depends that may cause this?
Thanks.
I created separate examples of classes and child classes but it didn't work in any of the cases. This, to me, means that the error may be caused by other frameworks.

The error happens in your IDE? In SBT? Both? Even if S had some kind of meaning, Symbol should have the precedence. Is it really a S? Not a special symbol? ‍♂️

Hello. It's in SBT. Everywhere I put the "Symbol" class, it gives that error.
